# trying to make a fixed window in doodle jump

Tags: javascript

how do you make doodle jump so you wont go through the wall? 
I tried to change this code:

```
//Make the player move through walls
    if (player.x > width) player.x = 0 - player.width;
    else if (player.x < 0 - player.width) player.x = width;
```

this is the link:
http://codepen.io/atatwalker/pen/JdmGMp

I am new and only ten years old